# Highlight whole street in a Google Map with API

Tags: google-maps

I'm having a bit of a problem figuring out how to highlight a whole street on a google map with the API. As in, say I wanted to show some data about a particular road on the map embedded on my website, how could I make it so this road turns a specific colour, reflecting the data?

Answer (score 0):

It is basically done by using directions object of Google Maps to plot a route between two arbitrary street points in the map. The points must be encoded with their LatLng coordinates. Here is a code example (as said this is API V2):

```
function initMap() {  // called by page onload event
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    // set the initial location 
    gMap = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    gMap.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    gMap.setCenter(GLatLng(49.238326, 6.977761), 15);
// init directions object and attach listener to handle route loads from function     highliteRoute()
    gDir = new GDirections();
    gPoly = null;
    GEvent.addListener(gDir, 'load', function(){
      gPoly = gDir.getPolyline();
      gMap.addOverlay(gPoly);

      // zoom & pan to poly        
      var polyBds  = gPoly.getBounds();
      var polyZoom = gMap.getBoundsZoomLevel(polyBds);
      gMap.setZoom(polyZoom);
      gMap.panTo(polyBds.getCenter());
    });
  }
}

function highliteRoute(){
  if(gPoly!=null)  gPoly.hide();
  gDir.load('from: 49.313530,6.969109 to: 49.238326,6.977761', {getPolyline:true});
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do that without the latitude and longitude? As in, just give it a street name instead?

Comment: I dont think its possible without using Latitude and Longitude

Comment: What script should I load from the Directions API?